# pandas ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
type      id      date         code
exact    9720    2017-10-01    515
exact    9720    2017-10-01    515
fuzzy    8242    2017-11-01    122
fuzzy    8242    2017-11-01    122
```

I was trying

```
exact_rows = df['type'] != 'fuzzy'
grouped = df.loc[~exact_rows].groupby('id').apply(
            lambda g: g.sort_values('date', ascending=True))

a = np.where(grouped['code'].transform('nunique') == 1, 20, 0)
```

but I got an error,

```
ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results
```

I am wondering how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is `groupby.apply` return `DataFrame`, not `DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```
grouped = df.loc[~exact_rows].groupby('id').apply(
            lambda g: g.sort_values('date', ascending=True))

print (grouped)
         type    id        date  code
id                                   
8242 2  fuzzy  8242  2017-11-01   122
     3  fuzzy  8242  2017-11-01   122
```

So solution for sorting values per groups is use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by 2 columns before `groupby('id')`:

```
exact_rows = df['type'] != 'fuzzy'
grouped = df.loc[~exact_rows].sort_values(['id','date'], ascending=True).groupby('id')

a = np.where(grouped['code'].transform('nunique') == 1, 20, 0)
print (a)
[20 20]
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you have to use transform in a groupby object, so just regroup with the existing whatever index

```
grouped.groupby(grouped.index)['code'].transform('nunique')
```